# How do i display an objects integer value in a text view from another class?

Tags: java, android

I have a String in a class that is separate from another class and in this string i want to get an integer from an object of the other class, this object is in a class of its own.

Class with string below

```
TextView2.setText(//I want the objects integer value displayed here);
```

Class with object below

```
testClass Object = new testClass();
Object.setIntegerValue(5);
```

Class of which object was created from below

```
int integerValue;

public int getIntegerValue()
{
   return integerValue;
}
public void setIntegerValue(int i)
{
 IntegerValue = i;
}
```

How do i display "Object"'s integer value in the TextView 2 without the app crashing?

Comment: "without the app crashing" - what is the crash you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextView2.setText(Integer.toString(Object.getIntegerValue()));`.

If you use just `TextView2.setText(Object.getIntegerValue())`, the `TextView` will try to find a `String` in `Resource` which id is the value of `Object.getIntegerValue()`.

Comment: the text view and its set text is in a different class to the object so i cant get a hold of it

Comment: `parseInt()` returns an int and it's not good to be used with `setText()` like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
   TextView.setText(object.getIntegerValue().toString());
```

Comment: to short an answer give at least one sentence explanation

Answer (score 0):

Just use the getter from the `testClass`:

```
TextView2.setText(Integer.toString(Object.getIntegerValue()));
```

Comment: `parseInt()` returns an int and it's not good to be used with `setText()` like this.

Comment: Oh you are right, I mean to say .toString(), I will fix it now!

Comment: How do i get the object for the textView because the object is in another class?

Comment: @user3786633 If you want to use any methods from the other class just make an instance of it like you did here: `testClass Object = new testClass()` and do something like `Object.method()` .

Comment: but i want the exact value that was entered for "Object" and not the value of a new instance. the value is not static

Comment: @user3786633 Then use the `Object.getIntegerValue()`, with the one that you made.

Comment: yes i know but i said that the "Object" is in another class from the text view so how do i get the "Object" from the other class and print its integer value

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getIntegerValue()
{
   return integerValue;
}
public void setIntegerValue(int i)
{
 IntegerValue = i;
}
```

I see an error here, when you call the `setIntegervalue()` function, you're modifying the value of `IntegerValue` variable, but you return the value of `integerValue`(which is different from IntegerValue) when calling the `getIntegerValue()` funvtion . Java is case-sensitive, so you're modifying and returning a different variable each time. See if this is not you're problem. 
This should do it.

```
public int getIntegerValue()
{
   return this.integerValue;
}
public void setIntegerValue(int i)
{
 this.integerValue = i;
}
```

and for your `TextView`

```
textView.setText(object.getIntegerValue() + "");
```